# Showing more than 1 desktop notification from firefox add-ons

Tags: firefox, sdk, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, html5-notifications

I'd like to show a few desktop notifications triggered from my firefox add-on but it seems like you can only show one at a time, from my testing.
I am not sure if there is any official way to do this, since I did not find any mentions in the notifications docs
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/notifications, but I'll take a hacky way, too.

Answer (score 3):

Did you say hacky?

```
var timers = require("sdk/timers");
var {notify} = require("sdk/notifications");

var i=0;
var timerId = timers.setInterval(function() {
  notify({
    title: 'Famous tities for '+(++i)+'00',
    text: "That's famous titles, Mr Connery"
  });
  if (i>4) timers.clearInterval(timerId);
}, 5000);
```

They won't stack (at least on OSX), and you might want to check what the default notification time by OS is before setting the delay to 5 seconds, but it's the best I can think of given the limitations of the notification module.

Not that you care, but I just show different notifications in my add-on depending on whether it's one or several; I feel like it's less intrusive.

```
function showNotif(notifs) {//notifs is an array
  var len = notifs.length;
  var notifOptions;
  if(len>1) {
    notifOptions = {
      title: len + 'notifications',
      text: addonName
    }
  } else {
    notifOptions = {
      title: notifs[0].title,
      text: notifs[0].text
    }
  }
  notify(notifOptions);
```

Then you need to add an `onClick` to `notifOptions` that does something different depending on whether it's for one or many.

Comment: hmm, i was looking for a way to stack them, but if it's not supported, what can you do. I'll test the intervals method.

Comment: @odle Yeah, I started writing this hoping that a shorter interval would stack them, but it just replaces them.

Comment: I added unique `tag` in `options` and multiple notification appear at the same time. I checked it on FF31 and Ubuntu 12.10