# How to add multiple desktop notifications with firefox addon sdk?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I need to create a simple way to be able to push out a multiple notifications on desktop using the firefox sdk in an add-on.

My code is:

```
notifications.notify({
  title: "Jabberwocky  ",
  text: "Twas brillig, and the slithy toves  ",
  data: "did gyre and gimble in the wabe  ",
  onClick: function(data) {
    console.log("click data: "+data);
    // console.log(this.data) would produce the same result.
  }
});
```

It's working well but not working in for loop.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288457/showing-more-than-1-desktop-notification-from-firefox-add-ons/21294939#21294939)

Answer (score 2):

From [Bug 935507](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=935507), SDK notifications do not stack. There has been discussion ([bug 616636](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=616636)) regarding how to deal with multiple notifications, as that's a strange UX problem. There is probably a better way to display information than for-looping a bunch of stuff to the desktop. What are your goals?

Comment: My goal is to show desktop notification one by one like chrome desktop notification.

Comment: Is any solution for that?

Comment: Not currently due to that bug, but that may never be resolved, as spamming a user's screen with notifications isn't really good UX.

Comment: @jsantell i think this bug should be fixed.  It works on some OSes, I can confirm for FF installed on Ubuntu.  Though it didn't work on Windows.